# Fade in effect where letters reveal from a central location in a word

Tags: jquery, css, transition, dreamweaver, fade

I would like to know if anyone has been applying this more complex type of fade in effect in which the words fade in with letters spreading out somewhere from the center.

You can check out what I mean in this BBC documentary, it starts at 3:27 when the title *"reptiles and amphibians"* appears.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcS3LpwXhEM

I would like it if I could apply such an effect in my main menu on the main page (I work in `Dreamweaver CC` if it makes a difference).

Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to fade in every character with its own delayed fade. I don't know a generic way to write this in code. You can of course just define a CSS transition (transition for opacity with a certain delay) for every character, but that messes up your code.